# Inverse problem : Finding a vector bundle (resp. with connection), given its characteristic class (resp. differential character)

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Given a rank $n$vector bundle $\alpha :E \to M$, and an element $u \in H^k(BG, \mathbb{Z})$, $G=GL(n,\mathbb{R})$we can define its characteristic class $u(\alpha) \in H^k(M, \mathbb{Z})$ as $f_\alpha^* u$ where $f_{\alpha}$ is any classifying map.
I am interested in knowing :

> (i) What elements $ x\in H^k(M, \mathbb{Z})$ arise as characteristic classes of some bundle, and some choice of $u \in H^k(BG, \mathbb{Z})$ ? i.e. What are the necessary and sufficient conditions to be satisfied by $x$ ?
>
> (ii) given an $x \in H^k(M, \mathbb{Z})$ which is the characteristic class of some bundle, is there a known way to construct the bundle ?

The corresponding questions for vector bundles with connection are

> (iii) Given a differential character $ \chi \in \hat{H}(2k)(M)$, what are the conditions to be satisfied by $\chi$ so that it is the differential characters of some bundle $E \to M$ with connection $\theta$ for some choice of the compatible pair $(P,u) \in I_{0}^{k}(G) \times H^{2k}(BG,\mathbb{Z})$ ?
>
> (iv) How does one construct the bundle and the connection, given the data ?

Of course the questions are related to each other. If the characteristic class of a character is not obtainable as the characteristic class of a bundle, clearly the character does not arise from a bundle with connection.
If the answers are not known in full generality, I would still like to know some special cases for which the questions can be answered. One such special case that I know is of course the complex line bundles and their chern classes.
And I would greatly appreciate any references where I may find any clues/answers.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: I think you need more conditions on $M$ and $G$ to be able to say anything worthwhile. You are essentially asking for a classification of homotopy classes of maps $M\rightarrow BG$, and this a *difficult* problem in general. Even if you take $M=S^n$, then the question more or less boils down to which elements of $H_*BG$ are in the image of the Hurewicz map and even this is not known. As for $(ii)$, just choose a classifying map $f$ such that $f^*u=x$ and take $E=f^*EG$ for an explicit construction.

Comment: @Tyrone Thanks for the comment.You are right, the question is very broad. Can one say something about the following special case : Suppose $\chi$ is a differential character whose characteristic class $u(\chi)$, and curvature $P(\chi)$ both vanish. Is it possible to say whether this character arises from a vector bundle with connection ?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't know any of the theory behind differential characters, so I don't feel too confident answering your second set of question. I'm interested to hear any answers, though, so I upvoted your question. I would suggest maybe limiting yourself to the classical groups $O(n)$ or $U(n)$ and maybe to restrict to manifolds whose dimensions fall in the respective stable ranges.